# How to un-escape special characters in Python 3?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, rawstring

```
x='\r\n\t\t\t\t'
print(x)
```

The above code isn't working cos maybe of it is not recognising the special characters. So you could please help?

Comment: Or could you suggest a different method to write x?

Comment: What do you want to have happen? Perhaps it _is_ recognizing the characters and you don't want it to?

Answer (score 3):

Use a raw string:

```
>>> x = r'\r\n\t\t\t\t'
>>> print(x)
\r\n\t\t\t\t
```

Escaping is tedious:

```
>>> x = '\\r\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t'
>>> print(x)
\r\n\t\t\t\t
```

Answer (score 0):

To escape an escape sequence, you should first escape the backslash `\` character. So you need to add double backslash `\\` like this:

```
>> x = '\\r\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t'
>> print x

'\r\n\t\t\t\t'
```

Or you can print the raw format of the string which dumps the raw string as mentioned by jamylak

```
>> x = r'\r\n\t\t\t\t'
>> print '\r\n\t\t\t\t'

'\r\n\t\t\t\t'
```